# The type or namespace name "WebRequestHandler" could not be found

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I am trying to use the Dropbox.API code that is listed here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples/SimpleTest

I copied their Program.cs into my Program.cs without making other changes to other files in my solution/project.

I am getting

```
The type or namespace name "WebRequestHandler" could not be found.
```

[image]

Despite having this using statement:

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

The help text says to add an assembly reference, but I don't know what I would add.

I tried moving the `using System.Net.Http` to both inside and outside the class.

I am new to C# and .Net development so expect this to be a really newbie problem.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Have you included a reference to the System.Net.Http.WebRequest DLL? This is where the WebRequestHandler is found, not in System.Net.Http.

See [this article on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained/).

In short, you can add the reference to `System.Net.Http.WebRequest` DLL by right clicking on the project and doing `Add -> Reference`.  Expect a popup window to appear and then put a checkmark next to `System.Net.Http.WebRequest`.

Comment: in VS2017 programming for a .NET 4.0 targeted version, I had to run VS Installer, Change, add ASP.NET MVC4 because apparently, the dll for the System.Net.Http... namespaces is contained there.

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm this lunacy:) You can pull System.Net.Http via NuGet but not System.Net.Http.WebRequest:) System.Net.Http.WebRequest is to be referenced via "Add Reference".