# WebRequestHandler not available in class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

We are using the webRequestHandler class successfully in an ASHX handler file but I am unable to access it from a new .vb class file I'm trying to create.

I am familiar with this answer **but the .dll is already a reference in my project**
[The type or namespace name "WebRequestHandler" could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45959270/the-type-or-namespace-name-webrequesthandler-could-not-be-found)

```
'api.vb
Imports System.Net.Http
Public Class api
    public function postAPI() as string
        dim handler = New WebRequestHandler() 'Type "WebRequestHandler" is not found
        [...]
    End Function
End Class
```

The hander is essentially the same but works fine:

```
'httpHandler.ashx
Imports System.Net.Http
Public Class apiWebHandler
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler
    Private Function getAPI() As String
        Dim handler = New WebRequestHandler() 'works like a charm no compiler issues
        [...]
    End Function
End Class
```

Any idea why the WebRequestHandler isn't available here? If it isn't available in a class file what would you recommend we do to send certs via web request?

Comment: I'd look into the httpClient

Comment: @ClearlyClueless I don't think it's possible to send certs with httpclient

Comment: Wasn't aware you needed to include a cert. That would be correct. You could use [httpClientHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-7.0#methods) instead

Comment: Not sure what you;re trying to do, but I suspect you can achieve it using just an HttpWebRequest instead, in a VB class